# How are ERC20 token balances stored on the Ethereum blockchain

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, go-ethereum

I am really confused about how ERC20 Token Balances are stored on the chain. It appears that all balance data are stored as an member mapping variable:

```
contract TestCoin is ERC20Interface {
    ...
    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    ...
```

I am wondering how many copies are stored on the Blockchain. Say `balances` contains 10K records and the highest block number is 100. Now I make a token transfer and 2 records in `balances` changed and we get a new `balances`, and this transfer is confirmed by a new block 101.

```
 <------- [Block 100] <------- [Block 101]
              ^                    ^
              |                    |
           balance1             balance2
```

Where does the balance is stored? Is it possible to retrieve balances in block 100? (I guess we must be able to do so, because the blockchain could rollback).

I am using geth/web3/eth.

Answer (score 1):

The Ethereum blockchain has the notion of "state", where every contract (and address) has a state, and every block creates a delta (change) to this state. To get the current balance, you have to scan the whole blockchain.

So if I send you 50 ether, the block that will contain this transaction will effectively cause a -50 Eth in my account and 50 Eth to yours.

Same applies to that mapping you show there. The mapping contains only relevant addresses (addresses that are involved), and a delta in these addresses when tokens are sent to them in each block, when a relevant transaction happens.

Ths is the difference between an "accounting model", which Ethereum uses, and a UTXO model, which Bitcoin uses.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand how ETH works. Here I am talking about ERC20 tokens, which store the entire account/balance in the smart contract as a mapping.